# Inheritance from subclass in php

Tags: class, object, inheritance

Just for curiosity, because I have not found any information on it, I wonder if a php subclass can be subclassed, just like that:

```
class animals{}
class mammals extends animals{}
class dogs extends mammals{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the noise...
I've finally found an example that answers my question: it's possible that a sub-class inherits from a sub-class in php

```
<?php
    class boat {
        public function sink() { }
        public function scuttle() { }
        public function dock() { }
    }

    class plane extends boat {
        public function takeoff() { }
        public function land() { }
        public function bailout() { }
    }

    class boatplane extends plane {
    }

    $obj = new boatplane();
?>
```

Comment: This is a weird class hierarchy... you're pretty much saying that a place is a boat.

Comment: Thank you Robert,

Comment: Thank you @Robert,
yes I'm aware of that. As I said it's an example that I've found surfing the Internet. This is the link [link] http://www.hackingwithphp.com/6/17/0/interfaces.

Comment: @Robert,
The point is that I was not able to find any documentation regarding the possibilty to have a class hierarchy like that: father class, child class that inheriths from father class, child class that inheriths from child, etc.
I don't know if I will face a real project that will need such as class hierarchy, but I was in doubt, because all the examples that I had found were like father class, child class that inherits from father and stop.
Regards